# How to override hover color of main nav bar button in bootstrap freelancer template?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm struggling with main navigation button menu hover color when working with official freelancer template:

https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-freelancer
https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-freelancer/

Main button appears on narrower screens and should have the same hover color #128f76 like Send button from contact form on page bottom but it's blue #0062cc.

It seems that style responsible for this behavior is:

```
button.bg-primary:focus, button.bg-primary:hover
```

and is not overriden by styles specified in custom freelancer.css.

Answer (score 0):

the style of the menu button on mobile devices is

```
a.bg-primary:focus, a.bg-primary:hover, button.bg-primary:focus, button.bg-primary:hover {
background-color: #0062cc !important;
}
```

this style is in the bootstrap.css file.
you should override this bg color by add this code to your CSS file

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Sorry for my ignorance but I can’t find style specified by you in https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-freelancer/blob/master/css/freelancer.css also blue color isn’t specified in that file.

Comment: I edit the answer the code is in the bootstrap.css file and you should add this code to your CSS file and override the colour

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by changing following files (making as little as possible changes)

- index.html - remove bg_primary class, add btn btn-primary classes to Menu button

from

```
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right text-uppercase bg-primary text-white rounded"
```

to

```
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right text-uppercase btn btn-primary text-white rounded"
```

- freelancer.css - remove btn class, add missing important! to btn-primary selectors

from

```
.btn {
  border-width: 2px;
}

...

.btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary:active {
  background-color: #128f76;
  border-color: #128f76;
}
```

to

```
.btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary:active {
  background-color: #128f76 !important;
  border-color: #128f76 !important;
}
```